# How to install the Qt WebGL streaming plugin?

Tags: qt

[Qt Quick WebGL Streaming](https://www.qt.io/blog/2018/11/23/qt-quick-webgl-release-512) is a technology by which any Qt Quick ("QML") application can display its user interface to a user connecting via a web browser. It is provided as a [Qt platform plugin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpa.html) in a library called `libqwebgl.so`. However, the Ubuntu 19.10 distribution does not contain it, and seemingly Ubuntu 20.04 does also not contain it.

How can I install it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install the dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt install qtbase5-private-dev libqt5websockets5-dev
   ```
2. Download the source code of the Qt WebGL Streaming plugin. Here we choose Qt 5.12.4, as suitable for Ubuntu 19.10. Choose a different version from the [Qt downloads page](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/) if your distribution comes with a different version of Qt.

   ```
   wget https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.4/submodules/qtwebglplugin-everywhere-src-5.12.4.zip
   ```

   Alternatively, you can also clone the repository:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/qt/qtwebglplugin
   ```
3. The usual build process: unpack the archive, run `qmake`, then run `make`.
4. Copy the resulting `libqwebgl.so` library to where Qt processes look for the platform plugins:

   ```
   sudo cp build/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/
   ```

Comment: Looks like on Ubuntu 22.04 they have a lot of link errors, for example: `/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5ThemeSupport.a(qdbusmenuadaptor.o): in function `QDBusMenuAdaptor::QDBusMenuAdaptor(QDBusPlatformMenu*)':
(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `QDBusAbstractAdaptor::QDBusAbstractAdaptor(QObject*)'`